# How to output this figure using recursion

Tags: c#, recursion

The number n is entered from the keyboard (in this case, n = 7), you need to output such a figure

How to beautifully combine these 2 functions into one?

```cs
static void printD(int N, int k)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= k / 2; i++)
        Console.Write(" ");

    for (int i = 1; i <= N - k + 1; i++)
        Console.Write("*");

    Console.WriteLine();

    if (k < N)
        printD(N, k + 2);
}

static void printU(int N, int k)
{
    for (int c = 1; c <= N / 2 + 1 - k; c++)
        Console.Write(" ");

    for (int c = 1; c <= k * 2 - 1; c++)
        Console.Write("*");

    Console.WriteLine();

    if (k < N / 2 + 1)
        printD(N, k + 1);
}
```

[image]

Comment: So basically, what you need now is combing  upper triangle logic from `print2` with recursive approach from `print` - everything is on the table

Comment: I have updated the question, please tell me how you can combine these 2 functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest extracting a method which prints a *single line*:

```
static bool printLine(int N, int k) {
  if (k <= 0 || k > N)
    return false;
    
  Console.Write(new string(' ', (N - k) / 2));
  Console.Write(new string('*', k));
    
  return true;  
}
```

Then we can easily implement recursive printing for *down* and *up* triangles:

```
static void printD(int N, int k) {
  if (printLine(N, k)) {
    Console.WriteLine();
    printD(N, k - 2);
  }       
}

static void printU(int N, int k) {
  if (printLine(N, k)) {
    Console.WriteLine();
    printU(N, k + 2);
  }      
}
```

Finally, to draw a diamond shape figure we have to print up and then down triangles. So in order to *combine* triangles all we have to do is to call `printU` and `printD`:

```
static void print(int N) {
  printU(N, N % 2 == 0 ? 2 : 1);
  printD(N, N);
}
```

**Demo:**

```
print(6);
Console.WriteLine();
print(5);
```

**Outcome:**

```
  **
 ****
******
******
 ****
  **

  *
 ***
*****
*****
 ***
  *
```

Please, [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/I3gUSG) with the code.